Text refusing to show in preview mode with Xcode and swiftui
As the title suggests, unable to get the scene preview for a game using Xcode with SwiftUI to display any text on the screen at all. I've tried a few guides online and even put my code into a code tool with some suggestions but to no avail. The background is loading correctly but I've yet to see any sort of text appearing anywhere on the screen.
GameScene code
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        // Set the pastel blue background color
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor(red: 0.74, green: 0.85, blue: 0.91, alpha: 1.0)

        // Add an overlay node to hold UI elements like the title text
        let overlayNode = SKNode()
        overlayNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
        addChild(overlayNode)

        // Add the title text: "Veg Shootout"
        let titleLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
        titleLabel.text = "Veg Shootout"
        titleLabel.fontSize = self.size.width * 0.07 // Dynamic font size, 7% of screen width
        titleLabel.fontColor = SKColor(red: 0.10, green: 0.50, blue: 0.20, alpha: 1.0) // Dark green color
        titleLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.size.height * 0.35) // Top-middle alignment
        titleLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
        titleLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
        overlayNode.addChild(titleLabel)

        // Debug: Print details about the title
        print("Scene size: \(self.size)")
        print("Title position: \(titleLabel.position)")
    }
}

Game View controller
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let skView = self.view as? SKView {
            let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
            scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill // Ensures the scene fits the screen

            skView.presentScene(scene)

            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            skView.showsFPS = false
            skView.showsNodeCount = false
        }
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false // Locking rotation for landscape-only
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .landscape // Landscape-only orientation
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}

Game Scene Preview
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

struct GameSceneView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SKView {
        let skView = SKView()

        // Load the GameScene
        let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 896, height: 414)) // Landscape size
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)

        return skView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: SKView, context: Context) {
        // No updates required
    }
}

struct GameScenePreview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GameSceneView()
            .frame(width: 896, height: 414) // Landscape size
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

